# How to make latitude and longitude global variables?

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I have made latitude and longtitude global variables.

It works fine in the `MyLocationListener` class as it displays the current location latitude and longitude but when it loads url ( `http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="
                + currentLattitude + "," + currentLongtitude
                + "&daddr=27.11,85.11")` ) in webview, it loads the value 0 and 0.

Why?

```
public class ShowMapActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
double currentLattitude;
double currentLongtitude;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            mlocListener);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="
            + currentLattitude + "," + currentLongtitude
            + "&daddr=27.11,85.11");

}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        currentLattitude = loc.getLatitude();

        currentLongtitude = loc.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),

                "Latitude is: " + currentLattitude + " Longitude is: "
                        + currentLongtitude,

                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

        "Gps Disabled",

        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",

        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: problem is that u are requesting gps values and then in next lines u try to instantly apply them to webview url. The GPS values are not ready yet. Move setting the url in WebView to onLocationChanged and it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put this piece of code in `onLocationChanged`

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=" 
        + currentLattitude + "," + currentLongtitude 
        + "&daddr=27.11,85.11");
```

Comment: Wrote following code but didnt work, webview loads url but didnt display anything just a white view.

`@Override  
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)    

  {  

   currentLattitude = loc.getLatitude();  

   currentLongtitude = loc.getLongitude();  
   webView = (WebView)   findViewById(R.id.webView1);   
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());  
   webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?"   + "saddr=" + currentLattitude  
     + "," + currentLongtitude +   "&daddr=27.11,85.11");  
   
   
  }`

Comment: Also try to direct  current latitude and longitude value under locationchanged method but didnt work.

Comment: And did you tried to read the url without showing it in the webview already? I've also used the onLocationChanged method in a test application and even when I was on the same spot it showed some different values (different in the meaning of the 10th digit after the comma). So maybe the webview is loading but then gets already different values so loading it over and over again?

Comment: As u said, When i try :  
`final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
          /** Using the web based turn by turn directions url. */
          Uri.parse(
                   "http://maps.google.com/maps?" +
                   "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" +
                   "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355"));
                intent.setClassName(
                 "com.google.android.apps.maps",
                 "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
          startActivity(intent);` in locationchanged method,
it works but why it doesnot work in webview??

Comment: And what does the webview show? Nothing or an error page? Because when I try to load the URL in a webview I get a Webpage not available" error. Even when I go to http://maps.google.com/maps it answers with the same error

Comment: it works when i change the geo-coordinates via terminal.  
`geo fix 27.307 85.77`

Answer (score 1):

add this in `onLocationChanged(...)`

```
 webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="
            + currentLattitude + "," + currentLongtitude
            + "&daddr=27.11,85.11");
```

Comment: displays nothing except white view.

Answer (score 1):

Your double variable is giving you the default values in below line.Because before updating the location below line is executing

```
webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="
            + currentLattitude + "," + currentLongtitude
            + "&daddr=27.11,85.11");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are opening the WebView in `onCreate()` function and you get the location in `onLocationChanged()` function. which it comes after, to solve this problem, if you want to always when location changed you update the web view, just put it inside the function `onLocationChanged()`, if you want it to load once you can use boolean variable in your `onLocationChanged()` to indicate that it is the first time you go in this function.

for efficiency: you better remove the updates after you get the location to avoid battery drain.